# How to send raw binary data over serial in C without non-native libraries in linux

Tags: c, linux, binary, serial-port, termios

I'm currently trying to send raw binary data in the format of decimal to an external device over serial. I currently have the data in a buffer array but would like it in a structure like this:

```
struct packetData{
   
    uint8_t sync1;
    uint8_t sync2;
    uint16_t messageId;
    uint16_t dataWordCount;
    uint16_t flags;
    uint16_t checksum;
};
```

I'm also using 9600 baud, and have all the termios settings set using `cfmakeraw` and I'm currently writing using:

```
  #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include <unistd.h> 
 #include <fcntl.h>   
 #include <termios.h> 
 #include <string.h>  
 #include <errno.h>   
 #include <stdlib.h>   
int flags = O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY;
    fd = open(device, flags);
    uint16_t buf_tx[BUFFER_SIZE] = {255,129,191,0,2057,0};
    if(fd == -1){
        printf("\n Failed to open port! ");
        return -1;
    }
    
    tcgetattr(fd, &tty);      //Get the current attributes of the Serial port 
    cfmakeraw(&tty);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, B9600); //Set read speed as 9600 baud                
    cfsetospeed(&tty, B9600); //Set write speed as 9600 baud              
    if((tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty)) != 0){
         printf("Error! Can't set attributes.\n");
         return -1;
    }
     
    else{
         printf("Connection successful! \n");
    }
while(x < 1000){
memset(buf_tx, 0, sizeof(buf_tx));
        
        tcflush(fd, TCOFLUSH);
        if(y < 5){
            if(write(fd, buf_tx, 5) == -1){
                printf("\n");
                printf("Error>>: %s\n",strerror(errno));
                y++;
            }
        }
        tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
        usleep(1000); 
        x++;  
}
```

This code isnt the full code, just the setup/write parts so no need to worry about its syntax. if possible it would be nice not to have that buffer array and just use the struct directly, but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: you *can* just use the struct directly.

Comment: What is your question?  It can't just be "How do I send binary data over a serial port using C;" that's a "code this for me" request, a task for which a library would adequately suffice.

Comment: @user253751 would I just put the struct name right into where I would normally put the buffer?

Comment: `write` takes any pointer. it doesn't have to be a char pointer.

Comment: You need the struct size as well and, if you want to maintain your protocol, you may well need to specify your struct as packed.

Comment: Your termios configuration is incomplete, and therefore not reliable. CREAD, CLOCAL and CRTSCTS in the c_cflag member should be configured.  Use of nonblocking mode is questionable.  Use of **tcflush()** and **usleep()** should not be necessary when writing (or reading).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have the serial port opening more or less in hand.  I prefer to set the [termios](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) member components explicitly myself, but `cfmakeraw()` is perfectly fine too.

What you should consider, is having a separate function to send one or more of those structures at a time.  For example,

```c
int write_all(const int fd, const void *buf, const size_t len)
{
    const char *data = buf;
    size_t      written = 0;
    ssize_t     n;

    while (written < len) {
        n = write(fd, data + written, len - written);
        if (n > 0) {
            written += n;
        } else
        if (n != -1) {
            /* C library bug, should never occur */
            errno = EIO;
            return -1;
        } else {
            /* Error; n == -1, so errno is already set. */
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /* Success. */
    return 0;
}
```

The function will return 0 if all data was successfully written, and -1 with `errno` set if an error occurs.

To send a `struct packetData pkt;` just use `write_all(fd, &pkt, sizeof pkt)`.
To send a full array `struct packetData pkts[5];` use `write_all(fd, pkts, sizeof pkts)`.
To send `n` packets starting at `pkts[i]`, use `write_all(fd, pkts + i, n * sizeof pkts[0])`.

However, **you do not want to use `tcflush()`**.  It does not do what you think it does; it actually just *discards* data.

Instead, to ensure that the data you have written has been transmitted, you need to use `tcdrain(fd)`.

I recommend against adding `tcdrain(fd)` at the end of `write_all()` function, because it blocks, pauses the program, until the data has been transmitted.  This means that you should only use `tcdrain()` before you do something that requires the other end has received the transmission; for example before trying to read the response.

However, if this is a query-response interface, and you do intend to also read from the serial device, you should set `tty.c_cc[VMIN]` and `tty.c_cc[VTIME]` to reflect how you intend to use the interface.  I prefer asynchronous full-duplex operation, but that requires `select()`/`poll()` handling.  For half-duplex, *with these exact structures only*, you can use `tty.c_cc[VMIN] = sizeof (struct packetData)` with say `tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 30`, which causes `read()` to try and wait until a full structure is available, but at most 30 deciseconds (3.0 seconds).  Something like `tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1; tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;` is more common; that causes `read()` to return a short count (even 0!) if there is no additional data received within a decisecond (0.1 seconds).  Then, the receive function could be along the following lines:

```c
int read_all(const int fd, void *buf, const size_t len)
{
    char *const ptr = buf;
    size_t      have = 0;
    ssize_t     n;

    /* This function is to be used with half-duplex query-response protocol,
       so make sure we have transmitted everything before trying to
       receive a response. Also assumes c_cc[VTIME] is properly set for
       both the first byte of the response, and interbyte response interval
       in deciseconds. */
    tcdrain(fd);

    while (have < len) {
        n = read(fd, ptr + have, len - have);
        if (n > 0) {
            have += n;
        } else
        if (n == 0) {
            /* Timeout or disconnect */
            errno = ETIMEDOUT;
            return -1;
        } else
        if (n != -1) {
            /* C library bug, should never occur */
            errno = EIO;
            return -1;
        } else {
            /* Read error; errno set by read(). */
            return -1;
        }
    }
    /* Success; no errors. */
    return 0;
}
```

If this returns `-1` with `errno == ETIMEDOUT`, the other side took too long to answer.  There may be remainder of the late response in the buffer, which you can discard with `tcflush(TCIFLUSH)` (or with `tcflush(TCIOFLUSH)`, which also discards any written data not yet transmitted).  Synchronization in this case is a bit difficult, because the above `read_all()` function doesn't return how many bytes it received (and therefore how many bytes to discard of a partial structure).

Sometimes the interface used always returns the number of bytes, but also sets `errno` (to `0` if no error occurred, and a nonzero [error constant](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) otherwise).  That would be better for a query-response interface read and write functions, but many programmers find this use case "odd", even though it is perfectly okay by POSIX.1 standard (which is the relevant standard here).

Comment: Your description of **tcflush()** vs **tcdrain()** is accurate, but there are numerous other inaccuracies, especially your examples of VMIN and VTIME.

Comment: @sawdust: You mean, like the fact that `.c_cc[VTIME]` defines not the read() timeout (as one might assume from the first mention), but actually the inter-byte timeout, i.e. having `.c_cc[VMIN]=5` and `.c_cc[VTIME]=5` possibly timing out a read operation after just under 30 deciseconds?  I left that detail to the man page.  No, I believe you are only making unfounded claims ("numerous" in particular).  Feel free to write a better answer instead of a snarky comment, please.

Comment: Instead of answering the just question, you provide additional but misleading information.  You fail to notice that the serial terminal is opened for nonblocking mode, hence VMIN and VTIME settings will be ignored.   *"you can use... tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 30"* -- Even if blocking mode was used, a 3 sec timeout is poorly explained (until you belatedly add the comment that the man page should be consulted) and seems overdone.  *"tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1 ... return a short count (even 0!) if ..."* -- No, when VMIN>0 (and blocking mode) at least one byte is always returned (while the device is connected).

Comment: *"There may be remainder of the late response in the buffer, which you can discard with tcflush(TCIFLUSH)..."* -- Bad advice IMO since the userspace program is not synchronized with the incoming data.  Instead have robust code that can handle all input and validate it.  Don't assume that messages align with read syscalls.  Don't assume a complete message is received in one read syscall.